# Different version between OpenSSH and OpenSSL in Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, openssh, openssl

In an Ubuntu Server I have installed from source the last version of Openssl and OpenSSH.
If I check the version installed of Openssl I see the correct version but, if I check the version of OpenSSH I see this:

> OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016
>   [Version of OpenSSH and Openssl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qfNs.png)

But I have installed the 1.1 version of OpenSSL.
I see the old version of Openssl used by OpenSSH.

How can I set the correct version of Openssl in OpenSSH?

Comment: How did you install them?

Comment: I have install it from source

Comment: You shouldn't use pictures of the text you want to show in your question.  You should copy the text from the terminal and paste the actual text.  It makes giving support easier.  The actual text is substantially easier to read and easier to work with.

Answer (score 3):

The current OpenSSH does not build against OpenSSL 1.1.0. There is a whole thread about it in the [upstream mailing list](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2016-November/035497.html) explaining the reasons why they did not want that.

If I see right, you installed the new version, but dynamically loaded libraries still stayed there.

The supported OpenSSL versions are written in the [INSTALL](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/INSTALL#L16) file in git repository.

Comment: You mean openssh 7.4 does not support openssl 1.1.x?

Comment: Yes. Nor any previous OpenSSH version.

Comment: I understand. There is a link where I can read up the OpenSSH site where I can read up better?
Thanks so much!

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking now.

Comment: There is a link where I can see the version of OpenSSL that is supported by OpenSSH?

Comment: It is written in the [INSTALL](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/INSTALL#L16)